# Android studio "x" to close tabs hidden?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

I had a colleague with a different keyboard layout work on my mac for 5 minutes and he pressed a lot of different (wrong) hotkeys.

Now the "x" in the file tabs are hidden and I can't use them to close files anymore.

How do I unhide the "x" ?

Comment: to close press alt+right click

Comment: I know that, but I would like the crosses back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable `Editor` | `General` | `Editor Tabs`, **Show "close" button on editor tabs**:

[image: show close button]

Or use `Help` | `Find Action` (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> on Mac, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> on Windows), start typing the option name, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to toggle:

[image: find action]

Or use Search Everywhere (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> with `Show IDE Settings` option enabled under the gear icon, <kbd>Enter</kbd> toggles as well, the lower entry opens Preferences at the corresponding page):

[image: search everywhere]

Comment: Thanks, this is really great support :), especially with the last edit.